# GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener not respecting View scale factor?

Tags: java, android, touch

I am using a [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener) to detect the [onSingleTapUp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapUp%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) event an a View.

The view has a scale factor of 5, therefore 1 screen pixel corresponds to 5 pixels on my view:

```
  view.setScaleX(5);
  view.setScaleY(5);
```

The problem I am facing is that the Tap event is not detected accurately. I looked in the source code of `SimpleOnGestureListener`, the relevant parts are:

- [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#594) the `SingleTapUp()` listener is called if the touch points haven't moved over a certain threshold
- [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#466)
  the travel distance of the touch points are calculated

I think the reason why the Tap is not detected reliably is that the distance calculation for the touch points relies on the scaled local coordinates of the view (`e.getX()` and `e.getY()`) instead of the raw coordinates (`e.getRawX()` and `e.getRawY()`).

Due to the scale factor tiny movements of the finger on screen will cause large changes in `e.getX()` and `e.getY()`.

Is my interpretation of the code correct? If so, how can I work around this problem?

For now my workaround is to intercept all events on a `View` that has no scale factor and then do the dispatching of the `MotionEvents` myself to the views that have the scale factor.

It works well, still I'd be interested if my analysis of the android code is correct or not.

I am using android 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, your analysis of code is correct!

Just some additional information which was found exploring source code:

- distance defined in variable [`mTouchSlopSquare`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#195) and initialized [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#406) (stored as square of original value, just for optimizations)
- if you pass Context to `GestureDetector`'s constructor (which should be, because second one is obsolete) then this value equals to `com.android.internal.R.dimen.config_viewConfigurationTouchSlop` according to [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java#310)
- comparison is touch in same area done in [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java#566)

### Workaround

As workaround I suggest you to access to private member `mTouchSlopSquare` of `GestureDetector` and add scale factor this distance calculation.

See my code below:

```
// Utility method
public static boolean fixGestureDetectorScale(GestureDetector detector, float scale) {
    try {
        Field f = GestureDetector.class.getDeclaredField("mTouchSlopSquare");
        f.setAccessible(true);

        int touchSlopSquare = (int) f.get(detector);
        float touchSlop = (float) Math.sqrt(touchSlopSquare);
        //normalize touchSlop
        touchSlop /= scale;
        touchSlopSquare = Math.round(touchSlop * touchSlop);
        f.set(detector, touchSlopSquare);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

```
    // usage
    fixGestureDetectorScale(mGestureDetector, scale);
    view.setScaleX(scale);
    view.setScaleY(scale);
```

I've checked and it works for me.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Thank you)